# Twitter List in iPhone app

Tags: api, list, twitter

I am looking to create an iphone app whose main menu will be a list of Twitter Lists. That part is simple. I was hoping there would be an easy way for each menu item chosen(list) to simply display the streaming tweets of all members in that list.  Not just an rss feed.  I would like it to display just like the lists display as they do in Twittelator and other apps, complete with avatar, time, links if any.  It obviously can be done because it is already being done, but id like my app to specifically concentrate on the lists only.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use [FHSTwitterEngine](http://github.com/fhsjaagshs/FHSTwitterEngine), it has the lists endpoints built in, along with every other endpoint you need. Plus, its synchronous so you can use it procedurally in a background thread.